# How set simple fade in/out effect on ajax tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a ajax data-attribute based tab code. Tabs content loads with ajax from PHP code by data-attribute. How I can set fade in/out effect on tabs content? I tried to do, but I'm not succeed.

PHP Code: https://ideone.com/ZMmk6f

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tab-entry").load('index.php', {
    tab: 1
  });
  $("#tab-entry").promise().done(function() {
    $("#loading").hide("normal").prev("#tab-entry").delay(1000).show("normal");
  });
  $(".tab-button").click(function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr("data-tab");
    var dl = $("#tab-entry").attr("data-load");
    if (tab !== dl) {
      $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").find(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
      $("#tab-entry").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("data-load", tab).hide('normal').load('index.php', {
          tab: tab
        }).next("#loading").delay(500).show();
      });
      $("#tab-entry").promise().done(function() {
        $("#loading").delay(500).hide("normal").prev("#tab-entry").delay(1000).show("normal");
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab-header0">
  <ul id="tab-header">
    <li class="active">
      <a class="tab-button" data-tab="1">1st Tab</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="tab-button" data-tab="2">2nd Tab</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="tab-button" data-tab="3">3rd Tab</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="tab-button" data-tab="4">4th Tab</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab-entry" style="display:none" data-load="1"></div>
  <div id="loading">Load ... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is purpose of `$("#tab-entry").each()`? Are there duplicate `#tab-entry` and `#loading` elements in `document`? `$("#tab-entry").promise().done(function() {})` would resolve a jQuery promise object immediately where a `queueName` is not used; are you trying to use `.load()` complete callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. I have notated and given a JSFiddle for reference. Substitute your page names and such in the ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function doAjax(content)
    {
        $.ajax({
            // Send to 
            'url': 'index.php',
            'data':{
                'html': content
            },
            'method':'post',
            'success':function(response) {
                // On done, fade out the current content
                $('#loading').fadeOut('slow',function() {
                    // On done, fade in new content
                    $(this).html(response).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            }
        });
    }
    // Load first content
    doAjax($('.active').find('a').data('tab'));
    // Onclick of the tab
    $(this).on('click','.tab-button',function(){
        // Remove the instance of active
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        // Traverse and add active
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
        // Load the ajax for this tab
        doAjax($(this).data('tab'));
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0pjcfq7c/1/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I'm trying to do like that